# Retrieving data from firebase firestore database on page refresh

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am designing a social media type application in angular and using a firestore database. I have noticed an issue where when I go from the profile page to the home page, all data loads perfectly, but if I ctrl + r to refresh the page the data is not retrieved.

It's behaving similarly for every component but Im assuming it will be the same solution for all.

While trying to debug this I put logs before and after the function which gets the data, and when I refresh the page the first log prints to console but the one after the function doesn't.

Here is the ngOnInit and the relevant onReload functions inside the profile.component.ts file. For reference the  this.firebase refers to my firebase.service

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("This Logs");
    this.onReload();
    console.log("This Dosent");
  }

  onReload() {
    this.getPosts(this.firebase.userData.uid);
    this.firebase.getFollowersCount(this.firebase.userData.uid).subscribe((followers) => {
      this.followers = followers;
    });
    this.firebase.getFollowingCount(this.firebase.userData.uid).subscribe((following) => {
      this.following = following;
    });
  }
```

Obviously its crucial that the data is always retrieved on page refresh so any advice would be appreciated as its my first time using firebase with angular.

Comment: Have you done any troubleshooting? For example, when you force reload the page, does the onReload function get called at all? Add a log statement and see if it does. If it does, step through that function and see which statement doesn't work. If it doesn't get called at all  you'll need to troubleshoot other code not included in the question.

Comment: Yeah I've done this and the onReload never gets called. The first log hits but the onReload and the second log doesnt hit which I can't get my head around